# What flag do I need to pass to java to limit the running time and memory usage of a .class file?

Tags: java, cpu-time

For testing purposes, I want to know if there is a flag I can pass to `java` in order to limit the total execution time and memory usage of a `.class` file.

*Motivation*: let's say that I automatically download someone else's code and I run it automatically, but I don't know if the code is (unintentionally) buggy and will crash my automated system if it is caught in an infinite loop or is increasingly using memory to the limit of the system.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952528/limiting-java-applications-memory-and-cpu-usage) that using the flag `-Xmx` you can limit the memory usage, but I can't seem to find the way to limit running time. Reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) it seems like there is a way of limiting the CPU usage during execution, but that is not what I want, I want the program ended (killed if necessary) if it has been running for more than, say, 5min.

*Example* of what I want:

```
java -Xmx1m -time5m a_java_program
```

for limiting memory usage to 1Mb and time to 5min.

Is there something like this for java?

Comment: Java alone probably can't do this, but I would imagine that your OS could.  What OS are you running it on?

Comment: In Linux you could write a script that polls "ps" and if after 5 mins your process is still there it will kill it. That should be easy to setup.

Comment: I am in Linux and MacOS. I was afraid of this. So, my only option would be to launch it as an OS process and keep track of it that way, right?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the Xmx option will limit the memory to the whole virtual machine, not a single class. For the running time, unless you have the full source code and you can run a profiler, you are in the same situation. A whole different thing would be if you were able to obtain the source code. Then you have several options to profile it for running time and memory usage (bear in mind that there will be some overhead by the profiler). For example, Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. So, `Xmx` will limit the memory of whatever `a_java_program` is (in the example I provided) independently if it is a single class or more? This is good to know, and I think it will still do what I need. With respect to profiling, I do not want to go that far, but I understand that there are not many options. I think for the sake of simplicity and automation, it is easier to launch it as an OS process and keep track of it. Thanks Josep, voting you up now.

Comment: There are actually lots of options for profiling. For quick and automated testing just call the command prefixed by `time` and you will get the running time and you can monitor memory usage in another process and kill it whenever necessary as Oleg mentioned in the comment above. Take a look at this: http://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/