# Apache Ignite Resource Configuration (CPUs, Memory Size, ...)

Tags: memory, configuration, cpu, ignite, off-heap

I'm using Apache Ignite to configure an In-Memory Data Grid (IMDG) cluster in localhost.
For each ignite node(process) that makes up the IMDG cluster,
I would like to configure 1) the capacity of off-heap memory, 2) the number of cores.

**Off-Heap Memory Capacity :**
To configure this, I edited ‘defaultDataRegionConfiguration’ in the ignite default configuration XML file
as guided in the link below. Is that correct?

- https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.14.0/memory-configuration/data-regions

```
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                <property name="initialSize" value="#{Size}"/>
                <property name="maxSize" value="#{Size}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

**The Number of Cores (vCPU) :**
I couldn't find any guide regarding this configuration.
Please tell me how to configure it.

how to configure cpu(core) count & memory size in single ignite node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're correct. You set the off-heap memory in the data region configuration
2. You're generally best giving servers a complete machine (or at least container). Threadpool sizes are calculated based on the number of cores in a machine, for example. But if you *really* want to do it, Java does not provide a simple way but you can use [tasksets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65163113/2998)

Comment: Does it mean that when I set the thread pool size, the number of cores is automatically calculated?

Comment: Should I use kubernetes or yarn, mesos?

Comment: The other way around: it calculates the threadpool sizes based on the number of cores it finds.

Comment: I wouldn’t use k8s _just_ to limit the core count.